# Should we merge firefox tags?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I noticed we have a [firefox] tag and then several version specific firefox tags. It would seem to me that the hypernym [firefox] should be sufficient. Should we merge these?

Comment: Behaviour can change radically between browser versions; the version-specific tags help in classifying a post.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, they should not be merged. There are specific XUL and XPCOM differences between the versions.